# Does windows 10 have a feature that automatically resets all folder ntfs permissions on boot drive?

Tags: windows-10

I have noticed that my Windows 10 laptop, which has folders I use as a developer, which are subdirectories of C:\ drive which is my boot drive, and which have permissions allowing my user account to read and write, are being periodically reset.  My write access is being removed. It seems to occur when Windows 10 KB updates are installed, prior to the message that Windows has been upgraded and that the system will reboot.

Is this is a known "feature" in Windows 10? Can it be disabled?  Does Windows 10 think that no folders should exist in the root of the boot drive that are user-writeable by default?

Comment: Unless the user isn’t an Administrator you should have access to the folder you describe just requires a UAC prompt to allow it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a "feature" of the Windows update process to reset permission on files, folders and Registry keys. Though it is possible to prevent this, I have found doing so may prevent Windows updates from completing properly... ever again! Even restoring from a disk image did not fix Windows updates, (which seemed odd to me), so Windows had to be reinstalled.

You might be better off using a folder on a non-boot drive, or within your own User folder, which (so far) has not changed.

You should also be safe within one of the Windows special folders, e.g. *Documents*, even though it may be mounted at the time of the update. [These can be changed to another drive, for additional protection.](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/moving-your-personal-data-folders-in-windows-vista-the-easy-way/)